# Java recognise an error being thrown from another method

Tags: java, spring, exception, design-patterns, coding-style

This first block of code works fine and shows no warnings because IDE recognises that if we don't return something we are definitely throwing an exception

```
private ResponseEntity<String> callService() throws CustomServiceException {
   // some code here...
   if(someCondition){
   // some code here...
   return responseVariable
}else{
CustomException customException = new CustomException(SERVICE_ERROR_MESSAGE, 500);
throw customException; 
}
```

This code which does the exact same thing except throws the exception from another method fails as it shows a warning on the IDE that we have a missing return statement.

```
private ResponseEntity<String> callService() throws CustomServiceException {
   // some code here...
   if(someCondition){
   // some code here...
   return responseVariable
}else{
handleResponse(SERVICE_ERROR_MESSAGE, 500); 
          
}
```

This is the handle response method

```
    private void handleResponse(String message, int responseCode) throws CustomException {
       CustomException customException = new CustomException(message, responseCode);
       throw customException;
    }
```

I know I could just return null at the very end and it will never get there but is that bad practice is there a common practice for stuff like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion would be clearer this way (and it would compile):

```
} else {
    throw buildException(SERVICE_ERROR_MESSAGE, 500);          
}

private CustomException buildException(String message, int responseCode) {
   return new CustomException(message, responseCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no need in such a method as `handleResponse`.
Just print

```
throw new CustomException(message, responseCode);
```

instead of

```
handleResponse(message, responseCode);
```